# Why is "debajo" used in one place, and "abajo" in another?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

A magazine I was reading today had this:

"***Escriba las respuestas debajo.***"

...which I take to mean, "*Write the answers below.*"

It also had this:

"***Escriba el nombre del escritor o escritores de los libros biblicos que aparecen abajo.***"

...which I take to mean, "*Write the name of the writer or writers of the Bible books that appear below.*"

So in one case (if my translations are correct), the word "below" is written "debajo" and in the other case the same word is written "abajo."

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*,

> Indicando estado o situación, abajo puede referirse a cualquier lugar situado en el plano inferior: *Mis padres duermen abajo* (‘en un lugar indeterminado de la planta inferior’); mientras que debajo alude al lugar del plano inferior inmediatamente en contacto con el superior, o situado en la misma vertical: *Mis padres duermen debajo* (‘en el lugar de la planta inferior situado en la misma vertical del punto desde el que se habla’). Esto explica que debajo lleve siempre, implícito o explícito, un complemento con de que expresa el lugar de referencia: *Mis padres duermen debajo de mi habitación*.

But I would say the opposition "debajo/abajo" is getting neutralized and people tend to use them indistinctly.

Answer (score 1):

The words "abajo" y "debajo" have the same meaning but if you want to specify the situation such as "El niño está debajo de la cama" which translates to "The boy is under the bed", in this case you can only apply "debajo".

Comment: Why would "abajo" not work in the situation you describe?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon *debajo* often requires an object. When we use *abajo*, we can drop the object like *el niño está abajo.* (A lower place which is understandable in different contexts.)

Comment: Let´s make it simple, "Debajo de" means undersomethingmeanwhile debajo and abajo means like a dimension which situates under us.